# How to create an Enumeratee filter based on a Future[Boolean] instead of a Boolean

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.3

In my Play application, I'm creating an Enumeratee using the filter function:

```
val activeTeams = Enumeratee.filter[Team](teamIsActive)
```

My problem is that my `teamIsActive` function returns a `Team => Future[Boolean]` and the `Enumeratee.filter` method takes a `Team => Boolean` as parameter:

```
def teamIsActive: (Team) => Future[Boolean] = {
team: Team =>
  val teamSize = Future[Int] = teamRepository.membersOf(team).map {
    members => members.size
  }

  teamSize.map(_ > 0)
}
```

So, how can I use my `Future[Boolean]` with my `Enumeratee`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this isn't possible. You cannot resolve the future inside your predicate function. Instead you should fetch the team sizes first and then create a predicate function with the list of team sizes.

```
val teamSizes: Future[Map[Team, Int]] = teamRepository.sizes()
def teamIsActive(sizes: Map[Team, Int]): (Team) => Boolean = { team: Team =>
  sizes.getOrElse(team, 0) > 0
}

teamSizes.map { sizes =>
  val activeTeams = Enumeratee.filter[Team](teamIsActive(sizes))
}
```

This reduces also the number of queries to your repository. On the other side it can increase the number of data fetched from your repository. But I don't know your data structure.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I did a mistake in my question; `teamIsActive` is function which returns a `Team => Future[Boolean]` and not a `Future[Boolean]`